# Get request works in postman but comes back as "undefined" from the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

This request seems to be working on the server side since in Postman it returns an object with the expected values. Here is the back end code

```
const showStats = async (req, res) => {
    let stats = await Job.aggregate([
      { $match: { createdBy: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId) } },
      { $group: { _id: '$status', count: {$sum:1 }}}
      
    ]);
    stats = stats.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const { _id: title, count } = curr;
        acc[title] = count;
        return acc;
    }, {})

    const defaultStats = {
        pending: stats.pending || 0,
        interview: stats.interview || 0,
        declined: stats.declined || 0,
    };
    let monthlyApplications = [];
  
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ defaultStats, monthlyApplications });
  };
```

When I try to run the request from the React front end side of the application it comes back as undefined.  I am using Axios and it works just fine with other functions and in different areas of the application.

Here is the code that is making an authorized fetch request via axios:

```
const AppProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

    //axios
    const authFetch = axios.create({
        baseURL: '/api/v1',
    })
    authFetch.interceptors.request.use(
        (config) => {
          config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${state.token}`;
          return config;
        },
        (error) => {
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );

    authFetch.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
          return response;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.response)
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            logoutUser();
          }
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
```

This is the "showStats" function that I am having issues with:

```
const showStats = async () => {
        dispatch({ type: SHOW_STATS_BEGIN });
        try {
            const {data} = await authFetch('/jobs/stats')
            console.log(data)
            dispatch({ 
                type: SHOW_STATS_SUCCESS,
                payload: {
                    stats: data.defaultStats,
                    monthlyApplications: data.monthlyApplications,
                }
            })

        } catch (error) {
           console.log(error.response)
           //logoutUser() 
        }
      }
```

This is the "Stats" component where the showStats function is called:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useAppContext } from "../../context/AppContext"
import { StatsContainer, Loading, ChartsContainer } from "../../components"



const Stats = () => {
  const { showStats, isLoading, monthlyApplications } = useAppContext()
  useEffect(() => {
    showStats()
  }, [])

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading center />
  }
  return (
    <>
      <StatsContainer />
      {monthlyApplications.length > 0 && <ChartsContainer />}
    </>
  )
}
export default Stats
```

My brain might just be fried but I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I have looked through and didn't find anything that immediate stood out to me as an issue and I couldn't find any solutions online. However I am still learning and I am sure I missed something. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: So I am not exactly sure what I did but just randomly restarted everything and it is working now? Sometimes none of this makes any sense.

Comment: sometime it's the only solution you have